# ASP.NET Web Application Does not Autoredirect to Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, nuget-server

I have an empty ASP.NET Web application set up to serve a NuGet repository to our team. I created it as an empty web application and didn't do much else except add the NuGet.Server package to the solution and add a test package to the Packages directory.

I've published the application to IIS, verified that I'm targeting the right framework (4.0), and looked through all the posts I can find on the topic. I haven't been able to find a fix. Basically, when I go to `http://locoalhost/NuGet_Test`, I expect to get redirected to `http://localhost/NuGet_Test/Default.aspx`, but it doesn't happen. I can go to `http://localhost/NuGet_Test/Default.aspx` directly and everything displays fine. But I don't know why it's not going to the default. I'm concerned because I don't know what to do if this happens with other web applications in the future.

Also, I have verified that `default.aspx` is in the Default Documents list on IIS (7.0).

Comment: defaultdocument might be the ticket..check here  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/defaultdocument

Comment: try this in your global.asax... public void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes routeCollection;
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", string.Empty, "~/YourDesiredSubFolder/YourDesiredDocument.aspx");
}

Comment: Gave both a shot. No luck. Open to other suggestions.

Comment: @foxtrotZulu, just FYI, when i gave your solution a shot, I got the message that 'RouteTable.Routes is a property that is being used like a type.' Just took out trying to add a variable: `RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute`

Comment: sorry, try this... var routeCollection = RouteTable.Routes;
            routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", string.Empty, "~/NuGet_Test/Default.aspx");

Comment: Hey! That worked! Except I had to take out `NuGet_Test`. Thanks!

Comment: @foxtrotZulu, post as the answer so I can give you credit if you're interested.

Comment: Have you considered using third-party server like ProGet (http://inedo.com/proget)? It's free and will have quite a few more options for team development like caching, proxying, etc. (disclaimer: I work for Inedo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better yet, try this..

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "/NuGet_Test","~/Default.aspx");
}
```

UPDATE: This was the actual solution tmoore used, no extra method & slight change in the URL form...thanks tmoore

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var routeCollection = RouteTable.Routes;  routeCollection.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", string.Empty, "~/Default.aspx"); 
}
```